# SQLAlchemy model how to simulate PostgreSQL "SERIAL" datatype

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

so as the problem says, I want to set up a SERIAL column's counterpart in my SQLAlchemy model. Can anyone help me?

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
class Review(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "reviews"
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER,(???), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, db.ForeignKey("users.username"))
    bookisbn = db.Column(db.CHAR(10), db.ForeignKey("books.isbn"))
    review = db.Column(db.VARCHAR, nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.INTEGER, nullable=False)
```

Comment: You already have it. SQLA treats a non composite integer primary key as having autoincrement behaviour.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä thanks!